# PostgreSQL: stored proc to return a fake row from several ones with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, aggregation

consider the following table:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
1      1      0.9
1      2      0.8
1      3      0.1
2      1      0.1
2      2      0.15
```

I need to return only rows those match the following conditions:
Considering grouping by Value1:

1. From each group return all rows with Value3 >= 0.8.
2. If all rows in a group have their Value3 <= 0.2, then return only one fake row with Value2 = 0 and Value3 = max(Values3 in the group).

For the table mentioned the result would be:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
1      1      0.9
1      2      0.8
2      0      0.15
```

How is such logic implemented in PostgreSQL (e.g. with a stored procedure)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `union`:

```
select *
from a_table
where value3 >= 0.8

union all

select value1, 0, max(value3)
from a_table
group by value1
having max(value3) <= 0.2;
```

It is easy to create an sql function based on the query, e.g.:

```
create or replace function select_from_a_table(limit1 numeric, limit2 numeric)
returns setof a_table language sql as $$
    select *
    from a_table
    where value3 >= limit1
    union all
    select value1, 0, max(value3)
    from a_table
    group by value1
    having max(value3) <= limit2;
$$;

select * from select_from_a_table(0.8, 0.2);

 value1 | value2 | value3 
--------+--------+--------
      1 |      1 |    0.9
      1 |      2 |    0.8
      2 |      0 |   0.15
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.Value1,
       Value2,
       Value3
FROM   Yourtable a
       JOIN (SELECT Value1
             FROM   Yourtable 
             GROUP  BY Value1
             HAVING Count(CASE
                            WHEN Value3 >= 0.8 THEN 1
                          END) >= 1) b
         ON a.Value1 = b.Value1
Where Value3 >= 0.8 
UNION ALL
SELECT Value1,
       0             AS Value2,
       Max(Value3) AS Value3
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Value1
                   FROM   Yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.Value1 = b.Value1
                   GROUP  BY Value1
                   HAVING Count(CASE
                                  WHEN Value3 >= 0.8 THEN 1
                                END) >= 1) 
group by Value1
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/277f2/5)

Comment: Although your solution looks a bit complex, anyway, thanks for it!

Comment: @Akon Klin's solution will not work when a group has both `Value3 >= 0.8` and `Value3 <= 0.2`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want with a single aggregation:

```
select value1,
       (case when max(value3) < 0.8 then 0 else max(value2) end) as value2,
       max(value3) as value3
from t
group by value1,
         (case when value3 >= 0.8 then value2 end),
         (case when value3 >= 0.8 then value3 end)
having max(value3) over (partition by value1) < 0.8 or
       max(value3) >= 0.8;
```

This does assume that `value2` and `value3` are unique.

Comment: Also an interesting approach, although a bit complex then one provided above. In my case pair Value1-Value2 is unique, but Value3 can be any. Anyway, thanks for you solution!

Comment: And a little question: is it exist an aggregation function that returns "original value": e.g. "SELECT Value1, <identity>(Value2), max(Value3) FROM a_table GROUP BY Value3" where <identity> must return Value2 from the row which was choosen by max(Value3)?

Comment: @Akon . . . There is no such function, but `distinct on` and `filter` provide related functionality.